# JavaFX Adding Rows to TableView on Different Page

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

Okay, I've been working through some issues with this program and I think I've finally gotten it to a point where I understand what is wrong. I'm trying to follow this tutorial a bit: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm But my program has the add a row on a different FXML page than the Table View is on. I think the program is having trouble connecting the two. I've looked in to trying to find ways to make them talk to each other (put everything in one Controller and it didn't like it, tried passing the controller through the class and that didn't work {might have done it wrong though}). My program also has Integers and Doubles in it which are not covered in that tutorial so I've tried to figure those out on my own (probably better ways of doing it than I did).

But right now I'm just focused on figuring out why it keeps thinking

```
data = partTable.getItems();
```

Is null (line 77 in AddPartController). Any help or other FXML/JavaFX tutorials would be greatly appreciated (though I've already looked through a lot of them).

FXMLDocument.fxml (main page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?> 
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.*?>
<?import ims.Part?> 
<?import ims.Inhouse?> 
<?import ims.Outsourced?> 

<BorderPane id="main" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ims.FXMLDocumentController" >
    <top>
        <Label fx:id="mainTitle" text="Inventory Management System" /> 
    </top>
    <center>
        <HBox fx:id="holding">
            <children>
                <VBox styleClass="contentBox">
                    <children>
                        <HBox styleClass="topBox">
                            <HBox styleClass="subHeading">
                                <Label text="Parts" />
                            </HBox>
                            <HBox styleClass="searchBox">
                                <Button text="Search" />
                                <TextField />
                            </HBox>
                        </HBox>
                        <TableView fx:id="partTable" styleClass="dataTable">
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Part ID">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <PropertyValueFactory property="id" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TableColumn>
                                <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" text="Part Name">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <PropertyValueFactory property="name" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TableColumn>
                                <TableColumn text="Inventory Level">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <PropertyValueFactory property="instock" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TableColumn>
                                <TableColumn text="Price/Cost per Unit">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <PropertyValueFactory property="price" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TableColumn>
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                    <Inhouse name="Part 1" price="5.00" instock="5" max="10" min="1" />
                                    <Inhouse name="Part 2" price="7.00" instock="2" max="11" min="2" />
                                </FXCollections>
                            </items>
                            <sortOrder>
                                <fx:reference source="nameColumn" />
                            </sortOrder>
                        </TableView>
                        <HBox styleClass="modificationButtons">
                            <children>
                                <Button onAction="#addPart" text="Add" /> 
                                <Button onAction="#modifyPart" text="Modify" /> 
                                <Button text="Delete" /> 
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
                <VBox styleClass="contentBox">
                    <children>
                        <HBox styleClass="topBox">
                            <HBox styleClass="subHeading">
                                <Label text="Products" />
                            </HBox>
                            <HBox styleClass="searchBox">
                                <Button text="Search" />
                                <TextField />
                            </HBox>
                        </HBox>
                        <TableView fx:id="productTable" styleClass="dataTable">
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Part ID" />
                                <TableColumn text="Part Name" />
                                <TableColumn text="Inventory Level" />
                                <TableColumn text="Price/Cost per Unit" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <HBox styleClass="modificationButtons">
                            <children>
                                <Button onAction="#addProduct" text="Add" /> 
                                <Button onAction="#modifyProduct" text="Modify" /> 
                                <Button text="Delete" /> 
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox fx:id="exitButton">
            <children>
                <Button onAction="#closeProgram" text="Exit" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ims;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author chelseacamper
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;


    @FXML
    private void addPart(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent add_part_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addPart.fxml"));
        Scene add_part_scene = new Scene(add_part_parent);
        add_part_scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(add_part_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void modifyPart(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent modify_part_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("modifyPart.fxml"));
        Scene modify_part_scene = new Scene(modify_part_parent);
        modify_part_scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(modify_part_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void addProduct(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent add_product_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addProduct.fxml"));
        Scene add_product_scene = new Scene(add_product_parent);
        add_product_scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(add_product_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void modifyProduct(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent modify_product_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("modifyProduct.fxml"));
        Scene modify_product_scene = new Scene(modify_product_parent);
        modify_product_scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(modify_product_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    }    

    @FXML
    private void closeProgram(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

addPart.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane id="addPage" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ims.AddPartController">
    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="inOutGroup" />
    </fx:define>
    <center>
        <VBox fx:id="verticalHolding">
            <children>
                <HBox fx:id="topRow">
                    <Label text="Add Part"/>
                    <RadioButton fx:id="inhouse" toggleGroup="$inOutGroup" text="In-House"/>
                    <RadioButton fx:id="outsourced" toggleGroup="$inOutGroup" selected="true" text="Outsourced"/>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                        <Label text="ID" />
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <TextField promptText="Auto Gen - Disabled" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                        <Label text="Name" />
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <TextField fx:id="partNameField" promptText="Part Name" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                        <Label text="Inv" />
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <TextField fx:id="partInstockField" promptText="Inv" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                        <Label text="Price/Cost" />
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <TextField fx:id="partPriceField" promptText="Price/Cost" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                        <Label text="Max" />
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <TextField styleClass="smallTextField" fx:id="partMaxField" promptText="Max" />
                        <Label text="Min" />
                        <TextField styleClass="smallTextField" fx:id="partMinField" promptText="Min" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                        <Label fx:id="inhouseLabel" text="Machine ID" />
                        <Label fx:id="outsourcedLabel" text="Company Name" />
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <TextField fx:id="inhouseTextField" promptText="Mach ID" />
                        <TextField fx:id="outsourcedTextField" promptText="Comp Nm" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="fullWidth">
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthLeft">
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox styleClass="halfWidthRight">
                        <Button onAction="#addInhouse" text="Save" />
                        <Button onAction="#backToMain" text="Cancel" />
                    </HBox>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

AddPartController

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ims;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author chelseacamper
 */
public class AddPartController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    ToggleButton inhouse;
    @FXML
    ToggleButton outsourced;
    @FXML
    Label inhouseLabel;
    @FXML
    Label outsourcedLabel;
    @FXML
    TextField inhouseTextField;
    @FXML
    TextField outsourcedTextField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Inhouse> partTable;
    @FXML
    private TextField partNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField partInstockField;
    @FXML
    private TextField partPriceField;
    @FXML
    private TextField partMaxField;
    @FXML
    private TextField partMinField;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        inhouseLabel.visibleProperty().bind( inhouse.selectedProperty() );
        outsourcedLabel.visibleProperty().bind( outsourced.selectedProperty() );
        inhouseTextField.visibleProperty().bind( inhouse.selectedProperty() );
        outsourcedTextField.visibleProperty().bind( outsourced.selectedProperty() );
        inhouseLabel.managedProperty().bind( inhouse.selectedProperty() );
        outsourcedLabel.managedProperty().bind( outsourced.selectedProperty() );
        inhouseTextField.managedProperty().bind( inhouse.selectedProperty() );
        outsourcedTextField.managedProperty().bind( outsourced.selectedProperty() );

    }

    @FXML
    public void addInhouse(ActionEvent event){
        ObservableList<Inhouse> data;
        data = partTable.getItems();
        data.add(new Inhouse(partNameField.getText(),
                Integer.parseInt(partInstockField.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(partPriceField.getText()),
                Integer.parseInt(partMaxField.getText()),
                Integer.parseInt(partMinField.getText()),
                Integer.parseInt(inhouseTextField.getText())
//                Integer.parseInt(outsourcedTextField.getText())
                ));
        partNameField.setText("");
        partInstockField.setText(String.valueOf(partInstockField));
        partPriceField.setText(String.valueOf(partPriceField));
        partMaxField.setText(String.valueOf(partMaxField));
        partMinField.setText(String.valueOf(partMinField));
        inhouseTextField.setText(String.valueOf(inhouseTextField));
//        outsourcedTextField.setText(String.valueOf(outsourcedTextField));
    }

    @FXML
    private void backToMain(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent add_main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene add_main_scene = new Scene(add_main_parent);
        add_main_scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(add_main_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    }

}
```

Errors that you get when you click add and then Save (don't even have to enter stuff)

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$294/109927940.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ims.AddPartController.addInhouse(AddPartController.java:77)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no element in `addPart.fxml` with `fx:id="partTable"`. Consequently `partTable` is null, and

```
partTable.getItems();
```

throws a null pointer exception.

You need to inject `partTable` into the controller for the FXML in which it is defined:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Inhouse> partTable ;

    // ...
}
```

The `AddPartController` only needs access to the list of items associated with the table, so you can define a field for it, and a method for initializing it:

```
public class AddPartController implements Initializable {

    // ...

    private ObservableList<Inhouse> tableItems ;

    public void setTableItems(ObservableList<Inhouse> tableItems) {
        this.tableItems = tableItems ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then set the items when you load `addPart.fxml`:

```
@FXML
private void addPart(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("addPart.fxml"));
    Parent add_part_parent = loader.load();

    AddPartController addPartController = loader.getController();
    addPartController.setTableItems(partTable.getItems());

    Scene add_part_scene = new Scene(add_part_parent);
    add_part_scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
    Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    app_stage.setScene(add_part_scene);
    app_stage.show();
}
```

and then of course you just need

```
@FXML
public void addInhouse(ActionEvent event){

    tableItems.add(new Inhouse(partNameField.getText(),
            Integer.parseInt(partInstockField.getText()),
            Double.parseDouble(partPriceField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(partMaxField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(partMinField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(inhouseTextField.getText())
            //  Integer.parseInt(outsourcedTextField.getText())
            ));
}
```

(FWIW I have no idea what

```
partInstockField.setText(String.valueOf(partInstockField));
```

etc etc is supposed to do.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and explanations! I appreciate it. I'm getting "cannot find symbol variable loader" for these two lines: `Parent add_part_parent = loader.load();
        AddPartController addPartController = loader.getController();` Netbeans recommends I made a field called "loader" which I don't think is right, but if I do it it comes back with another error of "cannot find symbol method load()". Any ideas?

Comment: @Chelsea If you look at the code I wrote carefully, you will see that in the line immediately before `Parent add_part_parent = loader.load();`, I define a variable called `loader`.

Comment: You're right, that's 100% my bad. Thanks so much! I'm now trying to figure out how to get the table to update when you add something to it, but at least it isn't giving me that error anymore. (:

Comment: @Chelsea Well, technically, the table is updating, however since you replaced the scene that's displaying it, you're actually unlikely to see the update...

Comment: So instead of fully replacing the screen, is there a way to navigate to it where it doesn't get replaced?

Comment: @Chelsea Easiest way is to show it in a different window. You can make the new window "modal", so the user has to close it before returning to the original.

Comment: @Chelsea If you want to (start to) understand what's really going on (you are sharing the same data with multiple "views"), have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx. Then you can google "MVC" and "MVP" and "MVVM" and wander down some pretty big rabbit holes.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information! I'm looking into the making different windows stuff now. (:

Comment: I believe that for: partInstockField.setText(String.valueOf(partInstockField)); partInstock is an integer which he/she wants to convert to a string.